# LWR Theme Header and Footer with slots

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, community, lightning-apps, page-layout

I have recently made a new LWR site and want the header and the footer to be fully custom. I am quite new to Salesforce and the documentation on Custom Theme Layouts is very vague.

[image]

^^^ In the image above I have made a theme layout component and a page layout component. However theme header and theme footer still appear even though I am not calling them.

blankthemelayout (lwc) VVVVV

```
<template>
<div class="container">
  <header data-f6-region class={headerStyle}>
      <slot name="header"></slot>
  </header>
  <section data-f6-region class={sectionStyle}>
      <slot></slot>
  </section>
  <footer data-f6-region class={footerStyle}>
      <slot name="footer"></slot>
  </footer>
 </div>
```

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

 /**
 * @slot header
 * @slot footer
 * @slot default

  export default class blankThemeLayout extends LightningElement {
    @api backgroundColor = '#fff';

    renderedCallback() {
    this.template.querySelector(".container").style.backgroundColor = this.backgroundColor;
  }
 }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="blankThemeLayout">
  <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Blank Theme Layout (LWC)</masterLabel>
   <targets>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
   </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
     <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
        <property name="backgroundColor" type="Color" default="#feb8c6"></property>
      </targetConfig>
   </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I was wondering what I need to do to remove the theme header and theme footer as I can't find any documentation on them.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the slots in the template file

```
<slot name="header"></slot>
<slot name="footer"></slot>
```

and in the js

```
 * @slot header
 * @slot footer
```

you could remove it, or did I get you wrong?

And here is a quite good [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_layout.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you drag and drop the layout from custom component, this happens.

Instead select the custom theme from Settings-> Theme-> Theme Layouts->New Theme Layout, and add the custom theme you created using LWR layout.
[image: Screenshot of selecting Custom theme on SF Community]

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: How does this address the issue of the headers and footers?

Comment: the additional headers and footers are on the theme. you've put a "layout" within the default "theme" so there are double headers and footers.

Following the screenshot uses your custom layout AS the theme rather than placing it within the default.